# Bootstrap grid with special Order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

i want create this order with Bootstrap grid in normal width
`[3][2][1]` that shown in mobile view as

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

i couldn't use RTL Bootstrap because this destroy style of other jquery Element in my page
thanx

Answer (score 1):

myself find answer

```
<div class='col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-xs-12'>
[1]
</div>
<div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col-xs-12'>
[2]
</div>
<div class='col-md-4 col-md-pull-8 col-xs-12'>
[3]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use css flex with media queries (http://codepen.io/Kebten/pen/bdBPRe) :-)

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .grid {
    flex-direction: column; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    [1]
  </div>
  <div>
    [2]
  </div>
  <div>
    [3]
  </div>
</div>
```

For info on other useful features of flex see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/